# Decoding a .xwd image in Julia

Tags: image, julia, x11, decoding, file-format

I am trying to write a decoder for a .xwd image (X Window Dump), since ImageMagick is quite slow.
The only specifications I found are:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11/X11-0.40.80/xc/include/XWDFile.h?txt

https://formats.kaitai.io/xwd/index.html

From which I managed to read the header:

```
xwd_data = read(`xwd -id $id`)

function get_header(data)
    args = [reinterpret(Int32, reverse(data[4*i-3:4*i]))[1] for i in 1:25]
    xwd = XwdHeader(args...)
    return xwd
end

struct XwdHeader
    header_size::Int32
    file_version::Int32
    pixmap_format::Int32
    pixmap_depth::Int32
    pixmap_width::Int32
    pixmap_height::Int32
    xoffset::Int32
    byte_order::Int32
    bitmap_unit::Int32
    bitmap_bit_order::Int32
    bitmap_pad::Int32
    bits_per_pixel::Int32
    bytes_per_line::Int32
    visual_class::Int32
    red_mask::Int32
    green_mask::Int32
    blue_mask::Int32
    bits_per_rgb::Int32
    colormap_entries::Int32
    ncolors::Int32
    window_width::Int32
    window_height::Int32
    window_x::Int32
    window_y::Int32
    window_bdrwidth::Int32
end
```

and the colormap, which is stored in blocks of 12 bytes and in little-endian byte order:

```
function read_colormap_entry(n, data, header)
    offset = header.header_size + 1
    poff = 12*n
    px = Pixel(reinterpret(UInt32, reverse(data[offset+poff:offset+poff+3]))[1],
                reinterpret(UInt16, reverse(data[offset+poff+4:offset+poff+5]))[1],
                reinterpret(UInt16, reverse(data[offset+poff+6:offset+poff+7]))[1],
                reinterpret(UInt16, reverse(data[offset+poff+8:offset+poff+9]))[1],
                reinterpret(UInt8, data[offset+poff+10])[1],
                reinterpret(UInt8, data[offset+poff+11])[1])
    println("Pixel number ", px.entry_number >> 16)
    println("R ", px.red >> 8)
    println("G ", px.green >> 8)
    println("B ", px.blue >> 8)
    println("flags ", px.flags)
    println("padding ",px.padding)
end


struct Pixel
    entry_number::UInt32
    red::UInt16
    green::UInt16
    blue::UInt16
    flags::UInt8
    padding::UInt8
end
```

```
julia> read_colormap_entry(0, data, header)
Pixel number 0
R 0
G 0
B 0
flags 7
padding 0

julia> read_colormap_entry(1, data, header)
Pixel number 1
R 1
G 1
B 1
flags 7
padding 0

julia> read_colormap_entry(2, data, header)
Pixel number 2
R 2
G 2
B 2
flags 7
padding 0
```

Now I have the actual image data stored in 4 byte blocks per pixel in the "Direct Color" visual class. Does anybody know howto extract the RGB values from this ?

*edit*:
By playing around with the data I found out how to extract the R and G values

```
function read_pixel(i, j, data, header::XwdHeader)
    w = header.window_width
    h = header.window_height
    offset = header.header_size + header.colormap_entries * 12 + 1
    poff = 4*((i-1)*w + (j-1))
    px = reinterpret(UInt32, reverse(data[offset+poff:offset+poff+3]))[1]
    println("Px value ", px)
    r = (px & xwd.red_mask) >> 16
    g = (px & xwd.green_mask) >> 8
    b = (px & xwd.blue_mask)
    println("r ", r)
    println("g ", g)
    println("b ", b)
end
```

which gives the correct R and G values, but the B value should be non zero.

```
julia> read_pixel(31, 31, data, xwd_header)
Px value 741685248
r 53
g 56
b 0
```

I basically have no idea what I am doing with the color masks and the
bit-shifts. Can anyone explain this ? Thanks !

Comment: ImageMagick can also write XWD files, so you could generate some to test with... a red 8x8 `convert -size 8x8 xc:red red.xwd` or a red-green-blue row `convert xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append rgb.xwd`

Comment: Not a way to do it in Julia, but if ImageMagick is too slow, maybe use the xwdtopnm utility from netpbm?  Then you can pipe it to pnmtopng to convert to PNG, or one of the other netpbm utilities named pnmtoXXX.  Something like xwdtopnm <file.xwd | pnmtopng >file.png.  This should be pretty fast.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Your `read_pixel` method actually reads a color map entry from the XWD. The pixel/entry number looks strange, as I would expect them to be 0, 1, 2, but the other values looks good. Remember that these are 16 bit RGB values, shifted by 8 bits they will be 0, 1, 2. The actual pixel data comes after the color map entries.

Comment: Thanks @haraldK! If I shift the entry number by 16 bits, I get your expected 0, 1, 2.
Naturally my next question is how to extract the RGB values with a colormap ?

Comment: You need to first read the number of color map entries as stated in the header (the specs/sample code I have found is a little unclear whether this is *really* `ncolors` or `colormap_entries`). `visual_class` should be either 2 or 3 if you have a color map. The pixel values should follow directly after, and be indexes into the color map. You then use the map to find each RGB value.